# Filling an adapter from different LiveData sources

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm playing with LiveData and want to understand what it can do.
I want to fill my RecyclerView with data from different sources by switch(using filters if you like).

Filtering values inside an adapter is not an option.
So, I decided to use **MediatorLiveData** inside my view model.

Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE completed = 0")
LiveData<List<Task>> getActiveTasksLiveData();

@Query("SELECT * FROM tasks")
LiveData<List<Task>> getAllTasksLiveData();

@Query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE completed = 1")
LiveData<List<Task>> getClosedTasksLiveData();
```

Repo:

```
    public LiveData<List<Task>> getActiveTasks() {
        return mTaskDao.getActiveTasksLiveData();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Task>> getAllTasks() {
        return mTaskDao.getAllTasksLiveData();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Task>> getClosedTasks() {
        return mTaskDao.getClosedTasksLiveData();
    }
```

ViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private final String TAG = "MainViewModel";

    private final AppDataRepository mData;

    private MediatorLiveData<List<Task>> mMediatorTasks;

    public MainViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);

        mData = AppDataInjector.getDataRepository(application.getApplicationContext());

        mMediatorTasks = new MediatorLiveData<>();
        mMediatorTasks.setValue(null);
    }

    public LiveData<List<Task>> getTasks(){
        return mMediatorTasks;
    }

    public void changeTasksOption(int index){
        mMediatorTasks.removeSource(mData.getAllTasks());
        mMediatorTasks.removeSource(mData.getActiveTasks());
        mMediatorTasks.removeSource(mData.getClosedTasks());
        if (index == R.id.navigation_all){
            Log.i(TAG, "Add source: all");
            mMediatorTasks.addSource(mData.getAllTasks(), new Observer<List<Task>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(List<Task> tasks) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Add source: all - setValue");
                    mMediatorTasks.setValue(tasks);
                }
            });
        } else if (index == R.id.navigation_closed){
            Log.i(TAG, "Add source closed");
            mMediatorTasks.addSource(mData.getClosedTasks(), new Observer<List<Task>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(List<Task> tasks) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Add source: closed - setValue");
                    mMediatorTasks.setValue(tasks);
                }
            });
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Add source active");
            mMediatorTasks.addSource(mData.getActiveTasks(), new Observer<List<Task>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(List<Task> tasks) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Add source: active - setValue");

                    mMediatorTasks.setValue(tasks);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        mNavigationView = view.findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        mFab = view.findViewById(R.id.fabMain);
        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.mainRecyclerView);

        tasksAdapterLive = new TasksAdapterLive(mAdapterCallback);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 1);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(tasksAdapterLive);

        // set up bottom navigation listener
        mNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            mViewModel.changeTasksOption(item.getItemId());
            return true;
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);

        mViewModel.getTasks().observe(this, tasks -> {
            if (tasks != null) {
                tasksAdapterLive.setTasks(tasks);
                tasksAdapterLive.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        mViewModel.changeTasksOption(mNavigationView.getSelectedItemId());
    }
```

As you can see, I've decided to use **MediatorLiveData** inside my view model.
My main goal - change data inside adapter when **changeTasksOption()** called from fragment.

I use `removeSource()`, because how I understand it removes `LiveData` source from observing.
But, in my case it does not.

When I launch app, logs are:

```
MainViewModel: Add source active
MainViewModel: Add source: active - setValue
```

When I try switch to another source - logs are

```
MainViewModel: Add source: all
MainViewModel: Add source: all - setValue
MainViewModel: Add source: active - setValue
MainViewModel: Add source: all - setValue
MainViewModel: Add source: active - setValue
*** repeats about 100 times
```

RecyclerView is blinking

So, I kindly ask.
What am I doing wrong?
Did I misunderstood the documentation?
What really removeSourse() does?
Because in my case it does not remove sources.

In case my method implementing this is wrong, how do you suggest I do?

Thank you!

**EDTITED:**

After experimenting for couple of hours I've found solution. Yeep, this is bad(or maybe not?). But clearly this is not universal, because we do not use Romm + LiveData

Create normal Room functions that return List

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE completed = 0")
List<Task> getActiveTasks();

@Query("SELECT * FROM tasks")
List<Task> getAllTasks();

@Query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE completed = 1")
List<Task> getClosedTasks();
```

Created MutableLiveData in repo

```
private MutableLiveData<List<Task>> mTasksTestActive, mTasksTestAll, mTasksTestClosed;
```

Add theese functions to repo

```
public LiveData<List<Task>> getActiveTasksTest() {
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {
        List<Task> taskList = mTaskDao.getActiveTasks();
        mTasksTestActive.postValue(taskList);
    });
    return mTasksTestActive;
}

public LiveData<List<Task>> getAllTasksTest() {
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {
        List<Task> taskList = mTaskDao.getAllTasks();
        mTasksTestAll.postValue(taskList);
    });
    return mTasksTestAll;
}

public LiveData<List<Task>> getClosedTasksTest() {
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {
        List<Task> taskList = mTaskDao.getClosedTasks();
        mTasksTestClosed.postValue(taskList);
    });
    return mTasksTestClosed;
}
```

ViewModel changes:

```
public void changeTasksOption(int index) {
    mMediatorTasks.removeSource(mData.getAllTasksTest());
    mMediatorTasks.removeSource(mData.getActiveTasksTest());
    mMediatorTasks.removeSource(mData.getClosedTasksTest());
    if (index == R.id.navigation_all) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Add source: all");
        mMediatorTasks.addSource(mData.getAllTasksTest(), tasks -> {
            Log.i(TAG, "Add source: all - postValue");
            mMediatorTasks.postValue(tasks);
        });
    } else if (index == R.id.navigation_closed) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Add source closed");
        mMediatorTasks.addSource(mData.getClosedTasksTest(), tasks -> {
            Log.i(TAG, "Add source: closed - postValue");
            mMediatorTasks.postValue(tasks);
        });
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Add source active");
        mMediatorTasks.addSource(mData.getActiveTasksTest(), tasks -> {
            Log.i(TAG, "Add source: active - postValue");

            mMediatorTasks.postValue(tasks);
        });
    }
}
```

And now, by switching UI, I have my result. No more loops and everything seems go ok.

But still! This is a bad solution. Maybe something is wrong with Room?

Comment: `Maybe something is wrong with Room?` no you just need a different way to chain the selected option to the selected LiveData exposed from Room

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> public void changeTasksOption(int index){
>     mMediatorTasks.removeSource(mData.getAllTasks());
>     mMediatorTasks.removeSource(mData.getActiveTasks());
>     mMediatorTasks.removeSource(mData.getClosedTasks());
> ```

No this is not how it should be!

The selected option should be in a LiveData.  Then you can use `Transformations.switchMap {` against that LiveData to select the correct `LiveData<List<Task>>`.

```
private MutableLiveData<Integer> mSelectedIndex = new MutableLiveData<>();

private final LiveData<List<Task>> mMediatorTasks = Transformations.switchMap(mSelectedIndex, (index) -> {
    if (index == R.id.navigation_all) {
        return mData.getAllTasksTest();
    } else if (index == R.id.navigation_closed) {
        return mData.getClosedTasksTest();
    } else {
        return mData.getActiveTasksTest();
    }
});

public void changeTasksOption(int index) {
    mSelectedIndex.setValue(index);
}

public LiveData<List<Task>> getTasks(){
    return mMediatorTasks;
}
```

Also, you should bring your `mData.get*()` methods to return `LiveData<List<Task>>` from the DAO again, that was a better solution.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now got it!

Comment: @EpicPandaForce  I have a similar use case.  Does the Transformations.switchMap() operate on a background thread to get the Tasks data?  If not and the Lists are large then couldn't the switchMap() call be blocking on the main thread?  And is setValue() used on the main thread because that call is only on an int so should not be blocking?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning values from your repo synchronously in your previous repo code -

```
public LiveData<List<Task>> getActiveTasks() {
    return mTaskDao.getActiveTasksLiveData();
}

public LiveData<List<Task>> getAllTasks() {
    return mTaskDao.getAllTasksLiveData();
}

public LiveData<List<Task>> getClosedTasks() {
    return mTaskDao.getClosedTasksLiveData();
}
```

So when you call `removeSource(mData.getAllTasksTest())`, it synchronously fetches data from the repo and that is why you are receiving data from all the repos.

In your edited code, you are using a worker thread to fetch data, which means that your source livedata gets removed from the mediator live data before the repo returns any value.

Comment: Thank's for an answer! But why removeSourse does not really removes it?

Comment: It does but after the function call `mData.getAllTasksTest()` inside `removeSource(mData.getAllTasksTest())`. So you get data first, then livedata is removed. Try your new repo with previous code.